# C# : creating an error in struct implicit convertion

Tags: c#, struct

i Have a Struct called Bool, it's simply to represent bool values in 1 & 0 (thats not all of the struct, only where my problem is).

```
public struct Bool
{    
    public static readonly Bool Btrue = 1;
    public static readonly Bool Bfalse = 0;
    int value;

    public Bool(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public static implicit operator Bool(int x)
    {
        if (x == 1) return Btrue;
        else return Bfalse;
    }
}
```

what i'm trying to reach is in this pic

[the kind of error i'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBkq2.png)

i want the other line (Bool c = 2) to show me the same kind of error in (int a = 1.2) with a red line (i know that 1.2 isn't an integer, but i'm talking about the error).

i want that if the entered value (Bool c = 2) [I mean the 2], wasn't 1 or 0, an error is shown with a red line under the code.

i know about exceptions, but i want this error to be a compile error rather than an execution error (if possible)

Comment: Side note: That code doesn't quite work the way your think. Both `Btrue` and `Bfalse` will have a value of 0 since you're using the implicit operator to return either one before they've been set. Instead use the constructor to initialize the static fields.

Comment: i did say that's not all of the struct, thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

You cannot introduce new compiler errors. My suggestion is to treat `0` as `False` and all other values as `True`. This a very common approach used by many programming languages.

You could also use [Code Contracts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-8) or [Use Roslyn to Write a Live Code Analyzer for Your API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879356.aspx).